# How to show given map maps upper half plane onto unit disc minus one point?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

Given

$f(z)=\frac{z-i}{z+i}$

I wanted to show that f maps Boundary of upper half plane maps to boubdary of  unit disc minus one point.

I had show that $|f(z)|<1 $

But how to show surjectivity?

Boundary of H is Real line . I had show that $|f(x)|=1$ for $x\in R$ also as $x\to \infty \implies f(x)\to 1 $ and $x\to -\infty \implies f(x)\to 1 $

But How to show surjectivity

I do not know how to conclude result.

Any Help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x\in\mathbb R$, then\begin{align}f(x)&=\frac{x-i}{x+i}\\&=\frac{(x-i)^2}{(x+i)(x-i)}\\&=\frac{x^2-1-2xi}{x^2+1}\\&=\frac{x^2-1}{x^2+1}+\frac{2x}{x^2+1}i.\end{align}Clearly, you can't have$$\frac{x^2-1}{x^2+1}+\frac{2x}{x^2+1}i=1.$$But $1$ is the only element of $S^1$ which cannot be obtained by this process. In fact, if $C(x)=\frac{x^2-1}{x^2+1}$ and $S(x)=\frac{2x}{x^2+1}$, you have $C(0)=-1$ and $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}C(x)=1$. So, if $\alpha+\beta i\in S^1\setminus\{1\}$, $\alpha\in(-1,1)$, and therefore the equation $C(x)=\alpha$ has some solution, by the intermediate value theorem. So,\begin{align}S^2(x)&=1-C^2(x)\\&=1-\alpha^2\\&=\beta^2.\end{align}Therefore, $S(x)=\pm\beta$. If $S(x)=\beta$, you're done; otherwise, replace $x$ by $-x$.